# Best method to install Ubuntu on new ssd for thin client pc?

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a new ssd for a just acquired dell 5070 thin client I want to run Ubunu on as OS.

In the past I downloaded the Ubuntu image onto my main desktop Windows pc and then used Balena Etcher to flash Ubuntu from file to a ssd attached to usb port on Windows pc via adapter cable. Then installed the new ssd with Ubuntu into the new pc.

Is there an advantage or disadvantage to using this method as opposed to the USB stick method. It seems easier to do it as I have done in the past.

Thanks for your help. I am only slightly experienced with these activities.

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion so not suited for AU.  Whatever you like to use use that. Mind that "Ventoy" is a cool  new method where you actually put 1 ormore ISO's on a stick and you select one of them  during boot and can use it to store personal files you want to carry over to a new install.

Comment: An alternative way to install Ubuntu is to extract and clone from a compressed image of Ubuntu Server, log in and then install the desktop environment and other tools. Extraction and cloning can be done in another computer before moving the drive to the target computer. See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Read the whole thread before using the method. I suggest installing Jammy (version 22.04.x LTS).